# Invalid date when loading to snowflake

Tags: datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one dataframe with a column of date as string.

| Date |
| --- |
| 04/04/22 |
| 04/01/22 |

I convert it to datetime type using pd.to_date(). So the column has a type as datetime64[ns].

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-04-04 |
| 2022-04-01 |

After that, when I tried loading data to snowflake using
`df.to_sql("table", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, method=pd_writer)`
, the snowflake table shows the column as 'iInvalid date'.

I've tried with .dt.date() but then it converts the column back to string. why snowflake is not showing the date properly and why there is not an error when loading the data?

Answer (score 0):

OK. the answer right now seems to be converting the column from datetime64[ns] to object (date). though it is still object, it is a 'date' object. and when loading the data to snowflake after this change, the date is displayed properly